# Want to insert data in oracle number data type column as '001' instead of '1'

Tags: sql, plsql, plsqldeveloper

Want to insert data in oracle number data type column as '001'  instead of  '1'.

Here is my code:

```
create table TEMP2 (id number);

INSERT INTO TEMP2 VALUES(001);
```

When executing:

```
SELECT * FROM TEMP2;
```

The output appears as:

```
ID
1
```

I want to store number as '001' instead of '1'.

Comment: A numeric datatype doesn't have leading zeroes, this is a display format. You need either `TO_CHAR` with a format which shows leading zeroes or `LPAD`.

Comment: Display formats are the job of the client application. If you want a consistent display format then you could write a view with a `to_char` expression. Storage doesn't come into it.

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't store information that is only used for display purposes. If that is a number, then by all means store it as a number.

You can always format the *output* when displaying the values:

```
SELECT to_char(id, 'FM000')
FROM TEMP2;
```

If you don't want to do that each time you run a select, create a view:

```
create view formatted_temp
as
SELECT to_char(id, 'FM000')
FROM TEMP2;
```

Or create a computed column that does that for you:

```
alter table temp2 
    add formatted_id generated always as (to_char(id, 'FM000'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the column to VARCHAR2. Wether this is a good solution depends on your needs